# Parallel programming open cv c++ namedWindow imshow issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

The problem is relatively straightforward; I want a secondary thread to take control of the camera, while the main program computes feature extraction related operations on an image, and then when it finishes it retakes control of the camera. The problem in that when the secondary thread closes/ends it also closes the window where the video was beeing displayed. And if I try to reopen a window with the same name nothing happens, nothing is shown !!
(I started thread programming yesterday)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mu;
cv::VideoCapture videoCamera;

void shared_imshow(cv::Mat imagen, int id) {
    mu.lock();
    std::cout <<"id: "<<id << std::endl;
    cv::imshow("Shared Img",imagen);
    mu.unlock();
}

void playCam() {
    cv::VideoCapture videoCamera;
    cv::Mat imagen;
    videoCamera.open(0);
    int neko = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<150;++i)
    {
        videoCamera.read(imagen);
        //if (!imagen.data) { videoCamera.set(cv::CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0); videoCamera.read(imagen); }
        shared_imshow(imagen,0);
        if (cv::waitKey(30) == 99) break;
    }
    std::cout << "Break" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    videoCamera.open(0);

    const clock_t begin_time2 = clock();
    std::thread t1(playCam);              // create secondary thread
    //   Feature extraction, homography etc.
    t1.join();                            // whait for the thread
    videoCamera.open(0);           // Reopen the camera (sice it is closed when the secondary thread ends)
    cv::namedWindow("Shared Img"); // Try to reopen a the closed window
    cv::Mat imagen2;
    for (;;)
    {
        videoCamera.read(imagen2);
        shared_imshow(imagen2,1);
        if (cv::waitKey(30) == 118) break;
    }

    cv::destroyAllWindows();
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You are having a resource contention issue. Try reading on [mutex](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes)/semaphore to share resources across different threads.

Comment: have you tried creating the video capture and imshow once in the main thread, passing it to the child thread as a reference and then synchronizing access via a mutex or related synchronization primitive?  I'm not an OpenCV expert, but there is a lot of what appears to be unnecessary opening/closing of the VideoCapture.

Comment: Is this on Windows? (The backslash in one of the include paths kinda hits at it)